# Convert tree structure to hierarchical array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have puzzling with this problem for hours. I am using Angular and [angular-ui-tree](http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/website/filter.html) to create an editable tree with unknown number of leaves. 
I need to flatten and convert the tree into a hierarchical array in order to pass it to MongoDb. I am also using Underscore.js as a utility

```
var tree = [{
    "_id": 1,
        "title": "node1",
        "nodes": [{
        "_id": 11,
            "title": "node1.1",
            "nodes": [{
            "_id": 111,
                "title": "node1.1.1",
                "children": [{
                    "_id": 1111,
                    "title": "node1.1.1.1",
                    "children": []
                }]
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": 12,
            "title": "node1.2",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 2,
        "title": "node2",
        "children": [{
        "id": 21,
            "title": "node2.1",
            "children": []
    }, {
        "_id": 22,
            "title": "node2.2",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 3,
        "title": "node3",
        "children": [{
        "id": 31,
            "title": "node3.1",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 4,
        "title": "node4",
        "children": [{
        "_id": 41,
            "title": "node4.1",
            "children": []
    }]
}]

//desired output
//parentId is null for top leaf nodes, path is String made by the parents' ids


[
    { "_id": 1, "title": "node1", "parentId": null, "path" : ""},
    { "_id": 11, "title": "node1.1", "parentId": 1, "path" : ",1"},
    { "_id": 111, "title": "node1.1.1", "parentId": 11, "path" : ",1,11"},
    { "_id": 1111, "title": "node1.1.1.1", "parentId": 111, "path" : ",1,11,111"},
    { "_id": 12, "title": "node1.1", "parentId": 1, "path" : ",1"},

    { "_id": 2, "title": "node2", "parentId": null, "path" : ""},
    { "_id": 21, "title": "node2.1", "parentId": 2, "path" : ",2"},

    { "_id": 3, "title": "node3", "parentId": null, "path" : ""},
    { "_id": 31, "title": "node3.1", "parentId": 3, "path" : ",3"},

    { "_id": 4, "title": "node4", "parentId": null, "path" : ""},
    { "_id": 41, "title": "node4.1", "parentId": 4, "path" : ",4"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use recursion here to "walk" down the tree. Note that your input tree sometimes uses "children" and sometimes uses "nodes" to denote its array of children; I have changed it to "children" throughout.

```js
var wholeTree = [{
    "_id": 1,
        "title": "node1",
        "children": [{
        "_id": 11,
            "title": "node1.1",
            "children": [{
            "_id": 111,
                "title": "node1.1.1",
                "children": [{
                    "_id": 1111,
                    "title": "node1.1.1.1",
                    "children": []
                }]
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": 12,
            "title": "node1.2",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 2,
        "title": "node2",
        "children": [{
        "id": 21,
            "title": "node2.1",
            "children": []
    }, {
        "_id": 22,
            "title": "node2.2",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 3,
        "title": "node3",
        "children": [{
        "id": 31,
            "title": "node3.1",
            "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": 4,
        "title": "node4",
        "children": [{
        "_id": 41,
            "title": "node4.1",
            "children": []
    }]
}];


var flattened = flattenTreeToNodes( wholeTree, null, "" );
$("#output").text( JSON.stringify(flattened) );


function flattenTreeToNodes( tree, parentId, basePath ) {
  console.log( parentId, basePath );
  function createFlattenedNode( treeNode ) {
    var path = parentId?basePath + "," + parentId:"";
    return {
       "_id": treeNode._id,
       title: treeNode.title,
       parentId: parentId,
       path: path
    } 
  }

  var nodes = [];
  for(var i=0; i<tree.length; i++) {
     var treeNode = tree[i];      
     var flattenedNode = createFlattenedNode(treeNode);
     nodes.push ( flattenedNode );
     var flattenedChildren = flattenTreeToNodes( treeNode.children, treeNode._id, flattenedNode.path );
     nodes = nodes.concat( flattenedChildren );
  }
  return nodes;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id='output'>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple recursive function will do the job :

```
var out = [
];
var generate = function (collection, parent) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
      '_id': collection[i]['_id'],
      'title': collection[i]['title'],
      'parentId': parent ? parent['_id'] : null,
      'path': parent ? ',' + parent['_id'] : ''
    };
    out.push(obj);
    if (collection[i].nodes) {
      generate(collection[i].nodes, collection[i]);
    } else {
      generate(collection[i].children, collection[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

See example below:

```
    var tree = [
  {
    '_id': 1,
    'title': 'node1',
    'nodes': [
      {
        '_id': 11,
        'title': 'node1.1',
        'nodes': [
          {
            '_id': 111,
            'title': 'node1.1.1',
            'children': [
              {
                '_id': 1111,
                'title': 'node1.1.1.1',
                'children': [
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        '_id': 12,
        'title': 'node1.2',
        'children': [
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    '_id': 2,
    'title': 'node2',
    'children': [
      {
        'id': 21,
        'title': 'node2.1',
        'children': [
        ]
      },
      {
        '_id': 22,
        'title': 'node2.2',
        'children': [
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    '_id': 3,
    'title': 'node3',
    'children': [
      {
        'id': 31,
        'title': 'node3.1',
        'children': [
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    '_id': 4,
    'title': 'node4',
    'children': [
      {
        '_id': 41,
        'title': 'node4.1',
        'children': [
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
var out = [
];
var generate = function (collection, parent) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var obj = {
      '_id': collection[i]['_id'],
      'title': collection[i]['title'],
      'parentId': parent ? parent['_id'] : null,
      'path': parent ? ',' + parent['_id'] : ''
    };
    out.push(obj);
    if (collection[i].nodes) {
      generate(collection[i].nodes, collection[i]);
    } else {
      generate(collection[i].children, collection[i]);
    }
  }
};
generate(tree, null);
console.log(JSON.stringify(out,null,4));
//prints

[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "title": "node1",
        "parentId": null,
        "path": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": 11,
        "title": "node1.1",
        "parentId": 1,
        "path": ",1"
    },
    {
        "_id": 111,
        "title": "node1.1.1",
        "parentId": 11,
        "path": ",11"
    },
    {
        "_id": 1111,
        "title": "node1.1.1.1",
        "parentId": 111,
        "path": ",111"
    },
    {
        "_id": 12,
        "title": "node1.2",
        "parentId": 1,
        "path": ",1"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "title": "node2",
        "parentId": null,
        "path": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "node2.1",
        "parentId": 2,
        "path": ",2"
    },
    {
        "_id": 22,
        "title": "node2.2",
        "parentId": 2,
        "path": ",2"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "title": "node3",
        "parentId": null,
        "path": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "node3.1",
        "parentId": 3,
        "path": ",3"
    },
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "title": "node4",
        "parentId": null,
        "path": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": 41,
        "title": "node4.1",
        "parentId": 4,
        "path": ",4"
    }
]
```